# Creating a twitter bot for a Discord server

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy, discord.py

I am trying to create a Discord bot that will monitor my twitter feed and post messages into a specific channel on my Discord server. I know solutions already exist for this task (zapier and IFTTT) but I am also wanting to use this as an exercise to develop my coding skills.

I have been following [this example](https://gist.github.com/kyriog/54f81ef59f5d4139aa2f) but now I haven't been able to get this to run successfully. My problem is that the bot can successfully join the Discord server and monitor my twitter feed but it won't post the message. I have used a print statement (that `print(message)` line)  to determine that the bot does receive new tweets.

I have stored my access tokens and secret keys in another file called twitter_credentials.py (hence that import). I'm using the Tweepy and discord.py libraries, any help will be greatly appreciated - The code below uses << redacted >> identifying strings:

```
import tweepy, discord
import twitter_credentials

twitter_access_token = twitter_credentials.access_token
twitter_access_token_secret = twitter_credentials.access_token_secret
twitter_consumer_key = twitter_credentials.consumer_key
twitter_consumer_secret = twitter_credentials.consumer_secret
discord_token = twitter_credentials.token_twitter_bot

client = discord.Client()

class StdOutListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    """ A listener handles tweets that are received from the stream.
        This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout."""

    def on_status(self, status):

        if not status.in_reply_to_status_id == None:
            message = '@{0} : {1}'.format(status.in_reply_to_screen_name, status.text)
        else:
            message = '{0}'.format(status.text)
        print(message)

        channel = client.get_channel('<<channel_id>>')
        em = discord.Embed(title='Tweet', description='My Twitter Feed', colour=0xDEADBF)
        em.set_author(name='@ <<Twitter_handle>>', icon_url=client.user.default_avatar_url)

        client.send_message(channel, message, embed = em)


@client.event
async def on_ready():    
    if not client.is_logged_in:
        raise Exception('Unable to connect to Discord')
    else:
        print('Connected to Discord')

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(twitter_consumer_key, twitter_consumer_secret, callback = 'oob')
    auth.secure = True
    auth.set_access_token(twitter_access_token, twitter_access_token_secret)

    print('Starting Twitter stream')
    stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, StdOutListener())
    stream.filter(['<<twitter_ID>>'])

client.run(discord_token)
```

Thanks

Qui

Comment: It actually looks like that's a very old example.  It predates the introduction of asynchronous programming to the library, which is why it doesn't need `await` and you do.  You'll need to manually await the `send_message` coroutine from your blocking `tweepy` code.

Comment: Ahh OK - Thanks @PatrickHaugh. I'll see if I can find a more recent example with which I can use use to teach myself. Many thanks for stopping me from keeping on this dead end route.